# Flask uWSGI showing Java is not installed

Tags: java, python, systemd

I am trying to create uWSGI server with Flask. I created a virtual environment and started my flask application simply using python. It worked flawlessly.

```
WebSocket transport not available. Install simple-websocket for improved performance.
 * Serving Flask app 'sempersentry' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Now there is a library which I am using is `LANGUAGE-TOOL-PYTHON`. It requires java to download language tool. Which I have already installed and flask server is working fine as shown above.

When I try to create system service on Ubuntu 20.04 to serve uWSGI via .ini file. It started fine but show error about java.

Here are the logs:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.19.1 (64bit) on [Tue Sep  7 20:35:03 2021] ***
compiled with version: 9.3.0 on 07 September 2021 15:30:52
os: Linux-5.11.0-27-generic #29~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 11 15:58:17 UTC 2021
nodename: CASE
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 4
current working directory: /home/ahmed/sempersentry
detected binary path: /home/ahmed/virtualenvs/cytex-venv/bin/uwsgi
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
chdir() to /home/ahmed/sempersentry
your processes number limit is 30404
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /var/sock/sempersentry.sock fd 6
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
Python version: 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15)  [GCC 9.4.0]
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x55de28b0f3b0
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
python threads support enabled
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 166688 bytes (162 KB) for 2 cores
*** Operational MODE: threaded ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ahmed/sempersentry/./wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sempersentry import application, socketio
  File "/home/ahmed/sempersentry/./sempersentry.py", line 10, in <module>
    from sempersentry_methods import *
  File "/home/ahmed/sempersentry/./sempersentry_methods.py", line 14, in <module>
    from gdpr_thread import gdprThread
  File "/home/ahmed/sempersentry/./gdpr_thread.py", line 7, in <module>
    from microsoft_365 import main_microsoft_365
  File "/home/ahmed/sempersentry/./microsoft_365.py", line 15, in <module>
    from FINAL_EMAIL_PICKLE import *
  File "/home/ahmed/sempersentry/./FINAL_EMAIL_PICKLE.py", line 25, in <module>
    tool = ltp.LanguageTool("en-US")
  File "/home/ahmed/virtualenvs/cytex-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/language_tool_python/server.py", line 45, in __init__
    self._start_server_on_free_port()
  File "/home/ahmed/virtualenvs/cytex-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/language_tool_python/server.py", line 214, in _start_server_on_free_port
    self._start_local_server()
  File "/home/ahmed/virtualenvs/cytex-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/language_tool_python/server.py", line 224, in _start_local_server
    download_lt()
  File "/home/ahmed/virtualenvs/cytex-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/language_tool_python/download_lt.py", line 144, in download_lt
    confirm_java_compatibility()
  File "/home/ahmed/virtualenvs/cytex-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/language_tool_python/download_lt.py", line 75, in confirm_java_compatibility
    raise ModuleNotFoundError('No java install detected. Please install java to use language-tool-python.')
ModuleNotFoundError: No java install detected. Please install java to use language-tool-python.
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 66500)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 66541, cores: 2)
subprocess 66513 exited with code 0
Python auto-reloader enabled
```

I am using .ini file to store uWSGI configuration. These are pretty straight forward.

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:application
#uid = www-data
#gid = www-data
#uid = ahmed
#gid = gydpost
master = true
processes = 1
threads = 2
http-websockets = true
http-timeout = 240
chdir = /home/ahmed/sempersentry
set-placeholder = log_dir=file:/tmp/logs/
set-placeholder = log_prefix=uwsgi-
logger = %(log_dir)/%(log_prefix)@(exec:///bin/date +%%Y-%%m).log
log-reopen = true
socket =/var/sock/sempersentry.sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
py-autoreload = 1
```

Here is my system service file

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve sempersentry
After=network.target

[Service]
#User=ahmed
#Group=www-data

WorkingDirectory=/home/ahmed/sempersentry
Environment="PATH=/home/ahmed/virtualenvs/cytex-venv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/ahmed/virtualenvs/cytex-venv/bin/uwsgi --ini sempersentry.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have tried many things, I tried to install language tool globally and it did not worked. I even tried to install it with sudo, still no luck. Current version of installed java is `openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20`

Comment: This is not related to uWSGI. Your library `language_tool_python` requires Java to be installed. Make sure the user you are running the service as can use Java

Comment: @KlausD. yes it is root user for both